# Display location on Map using voice command -Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

how to implement display  searched location on Map using Voice Command in Xamarin Android

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I have tried like using custom voice recognition I will display voice command on text view..But I don't have idea   how to display marker on the location specified on voice command

Comment: Are you familiar with google Places API? One solution am suggesting is like, search for the place you are getting from voice command, and by using this Google places API, query the place, then get the latitude and longitude from the returned data, and show it on map.

Comment: Please follow [this](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3092445?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) link.

Comment: I have not tried with google places ApI,I Will try to  implement  by the way you have suggested ..

Comment: I cant see any other solution for this, Good luck then :) :)

Comment: Thank you sanoop :)

Comment: Hope [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59421/using-google-places-from-an-app) and [this](http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2015/05/google-place-api-with-autocomplete-in.html) links be helpful for a starter.

Comment: Thanks sanoop it worked for me :)

Comment: Ok, Can i post it as an answer so that following users/readers find it useful?

Comment: Yes sanoop sure :)

Comment: Posted an answer, please appreciate by accepting and up voting the answer :) Happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use Google places Autocomplete APi's, which will give a result based about on your queried place name, Once you got your place name over Voice command pass that to the places API, And also there are a lot of query params that you can pass with the api to increase the probability of the search place query

For that you use [this](https://developers.google.com/places/) to kick start Places API, [this](http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2015/05/google-place-api-with-autocomplete-in.html) shows the implementation of the Google places Autocomplete API, And also please follow [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59421/using-google-places-from-an-app) discussion about the api

[Here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) is the list of query params and structure

Hope this helps :)